# Play Framework i18n. How to route to language with not country code

Tags: scala, internationalization, playback

In Play I can specify my supported languages in application.conf via:

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "de", "en", "fr" ]
```

Lets say, I created three messages files. For example:

```
conf/messages (with german as default)
conf/messages.en
conf/messages.fr
```

Lets pretend, an incoming request has set the following header: Accept-Language = en-US.

Because there is no "messages.en-US" file, the default message will be taken ("messages" which will be in german).

How is it possible (is it possible at all) to configure Play, to take the language file ("messages.en") if language file exists? I am a bit surprised that this is not the default?

To make it clear: I want Play to take the "conf/messages.en" file, if a request has the language "en_US" or "en_GB" or "en_WHATEVER" in his "Accept-Language", if no message file with the requested country code exists.

If not, what is the alternative? Do I have to add a lot "language_country-code"-combinations to my "play.i18n.langs" config?

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "de", "en", "en-GB", "en-US","en-DE", "fr" ] // an so on
```

Hopefully not. Anybody having the same issue? I guess I am just overseeing something.

Comment: did you test that? My assumption was that "en-GB" will take "en".

Comment: That would have been my assumption as well.. ;-) Its just not the case.

If user has "en-GB":
I don't need an "conf/messages.en_GB" file -> "conf/messages.en" will work, but I still have to declare it in `play.i18n.langs`

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I just declared a lot languages in `play.i18n.langs`